# Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with parameter $\theta$ find $m_X(t)$

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with parameter $\theta$ find $M_X(t)$, moment generating function.

$m_X(t)=E(e^{tX})=\sum_x e^{tx} p_X(x)$

$$\sum_x e^{tx} p_X(x)= \sum_x e^{tx}(1-\theta)^x\theta$$
$$=\theta\sum_x[e^t(1-\theta)]^x$$

I need to simplify $\sum_x[e^t(1-\theta)]^x$

To do this I could use $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} q^k = \frac{q}{1-q}.$

However, how to show that $e^t(1-\theta)<1$?

But I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @Boshu Ok, I believe I understand except for, they use $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} q^k = \frac{q}{1-q}.$ but how do they determine that $e^t(1-\theta)<1$?

Comment: It is true on some neighborhood of $t=0$ (since $\theta>0$), which is all that is required.

Comment: You're right of course, this is not necessarily true. Which implies that the MGF is defined only for some range of values of $t$.

Comment: $e^t<1/(1-\theta)$ whenever $t< -\log(1-\theta)$ (since $0<\theta<1$ it follows that $\log(1-\theta)<0$). So the MGF is defined on $(-\infty, -\log(1-\theta))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb P(X = k) = (1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta, k=1,2,\ldots$. Then
\begin{align}
M_X(t) &= \mathbb E[e^{tX}]\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{tn} \mathbb P(X=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{tn} (1-\theta)^{n-1}\theta\\
&= \frac\theta{1-\theta}\sum_{n=1}^\infty((1-\theta)e^t)^n\\
&= \frac\theta{1-\theta} \cdot\frac{(1-\theta) e^t}{\theta  e^t-e^t+1}\\
&= \frac{\theta e^t}{1-(1-\theta)e^t}.
\end{align}
Note that the series only converges for $t<\log\left(\frac1{1-\theta}\right)$.

Comment: Can you just explain how $\sum_{n=1}^\infty((1-\theta)e^t)^n=\frac{(1-\theta) e^t}{\theta  e^t-e^t+1}$? Mostly just why $e^t(1-\theta)<1$.

Comment: This series does not converge for all values of $t$. So we need $t<\log\left(\frac1{1-\theta}\right)$.